# Can I have a local var in Scala as Volatile, since in Java it is not possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm

As far as I know a field in Java and Scala marked as Volatile, provides the happens before relationship.

In Java it is not possible to have a local variable within a method as volatile. However the Scala compiler seems to allow, such things, as in the code bellow:

```
def test: Unit = {
  @volatile var doNotStop = true 
}
```

Does it actually work the same way as in Java? What are the semantics of such code? How does it look in Byte code and in the JVM during runtime?

In Java, such variable if given to a closure, could be modified by another thread, therefore, it is mandatory to be final, right?

Comment: The reason why it is not possible in Java is because there is no way that one Java thread can access a local variable from a different thread.  I don't know Scala, but I'm pretty sure that even if you are able to do it, it would be a _Bad Idea_.

Comment: you can compile the code using `scalac` and decompile back with `javap`. I will give you the glimpse of what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**: The `@volatile` annotation looks like it is ignored when applied on a local variable, except if the variable can be escaped from this local scope inside a closure.

To make sure of this, we can checkout the bytecode corresponding to the following snippet

```
class Foo {
    def test: Unit = {
      @volatile var doNotStop: Boolean = true 
    }
}
```

The class file obtained using `scalac` can be decompiled using `javap -c -v -p`. Here's the relevant part for the `test` method:

```
public void test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: istore_1
         2: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            1       1     1 doNotStop   Z
      ...
```

Note that there is no information relating to any volatile access.

If we choose to declare `doNotStop` as an instance variable instead, then `javap` shows the following field declaration with a clear volatile flag:

```
private volatile boolean doNotStop;
  descriptor: Z
  flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_VOLATILE
```

However, your concern about the local variable escaping its scope is completely valid! Let's try this:

```
class Foo {
    def test = {
        var doNotStop: Boolean = true
        () => doNotStop = false
    }
}
```

Using `javap -p` (no need to look at the bytecode or flags this time) gives us the following definitions:

```
public class Foo {
  public scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> test();
  public static final void $anonfun$test$1(scala.runtime.BooleanRef);
  public Foo();
  private static java.lang.Object $deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda);
}
```

You can see that the closure has been compiled into its own method named `$anonfun$test$1` which takes a `BooleanRef`. This `BooleanRef` is the runtime representation for `doNotStop` and wraps a `boolean`. For more info about the last declaration, you can checkout the [related Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html).

Now for the reveal: what if we make `doNotStop` volatile again?

```
public class Foo {
  public scala.Function0<scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> test();
  public static final void $anonfun$test$1(scala.runtime.VolatileBooleanRef);
  public Foo();
  private static java.lang.Object $deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda);
}
```

The class stayed mostly the same, but `$anonfun$test$1` now takes a `VolatileBooleanRef`. Guess how its inner `boolean` is implemented:

```
volatile public boolean elem;
```

The semantics here are very clear: your not-so-local `Boolean` variable is represented as field of a `BooleanRef` instance at runtime. It is this field that may be marked `volatile` by the annotation. There you go, `@volatile` was useful there after all!

To answer your second question: Java's closure only close over values that are "effectively final", which would disallow this pattern where the value of `doNotStop` changes within the closure. You could of course implement it the same way as was done here, using an "effectively final" reference to a `(Volatile)BooleanRef` whose `elem` can be freely modified by the closure.